# What is a proof that $\space A, B, C\space$ be sets. If $B \setminus A = ∅$, then $A \nsubseteq C$ or $B \subseteq C$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How can I do with the contrapositive proof method? If I use contrapositive, proof is that If $A$ is subset of $C$ and $B$ is not a subset of $C$, then B-A is not equal to ∅. but I cannot prove this context.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The statement is that
\begin{equation}\text{if } P \text{ then } (Q \text{ or } R)\end{equation} The contrapositive is that
\begin{equation}\text{if } (\neg Q \text{ and }\neg R) \text{ then } \neg P
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much but I know this and could not prove it by applying. :(

Comment: It is the best help I can give. Why don't you include the exact contrapositive in the question? See @JoséCarlosSantos ' comment above...

Answer (score 1):

With what you have done, you can prove that there is an element of $B$ that is not in $C$ and therefore not in $A$, and so $B\setminus A\ne\emptyset$.